# Variance partitioning when using a response from 1st study as a predictor in 2nd study

Tags: mixed-model, variance, partial-effect

I use linear mixed-effects models to analyze my data, where I have a variable *C* that is used as a response and an explanatory variable in separate studies.

In the first study *C* ~ *A* + (1|*B*),
I found that *A* explained 37%, and (1|*B*) explained 35% of the total variance in *C*.

In the second study *D* ~ *C* + *A* + (1|*B*), I found that *C* explained 50%, *A* explained 0% and (1|*B*) explained 10% of the total variance in *D*.

Overall I am interested in the effects of *A* and (1|*B*) on *D* and the proportion of which that can be credited to *C*. I would like to approximately "decompose" the variance explained by C to *A* and (1|*B*). 
For example, *A* would explain 0% + (50% * 37%) = 18.5 %, and *B* would explain 10% + (50% * 35%) = 27.5% of the variance in *D*.

Would this be acceptable or is there a better approach? Any comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated!